# Sound processing in Android

Tags: android

I know there is a similar question to this floating around stackoverflow.  What I would like to know is if there's a simple way to do beat mapping for a song in Android?  I don't need to do anything as complicated as beat matching between different varieties of songs, as the other question requests; at least I don't think it's anymore complicated, more experienced programmers please feel free to comment.

I simply would like to map the beat of a single song to be able to use it later in my program.  I'm very new to both Android programming and sound processing in programs, so any suggestions or comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the open source (actually made by a member of the Android team) project RingDroid...there's some pretty basic sound processing there, so that should give you a start.

Here's the [RingDroid site](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/).